# Protools 10 on OS X 10.7.3 does not recognize 002r

Tags: pro-tools

I have Googled this for a while to no avail.  I just install Protools 10.1.2 on an iMac running OS X 10.7.3.  I have a 002r connected.  The 002 appears in the Audio MIDI setup window but apparently with no I/O.  Consequently, when I try to create I/O paths, the 002 doesn't appear.  I have installed the 002/003 drivers a couple of times.  The 002 does appear as a device in the Sound Preferences window but selecting it doesn't make the system sounds come through the 002, actually its just crashed the Prefs window a couple of times.  This is super buggy and I'm already having regrets.  Has anyone else got a 002r working with a similar setup?

Comment: when you say "I have installed the 002/003 drivers a couple of times" are you absolutely sure you have installed the latest drivers?
http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/Download/en379411